# Utilize Function in Child Theme / Template File

Tags: php, functions

With a plugin, I have used require_once in the init.php of a plugin that I have made for my site to make functions available.

With a child theme, where should I put the calls to require_once?  When I put them into the template file that uses it, it doesn't seem to work.

#### EDIT

I would have thought that this

```
locate_template('../../plugins/events-and-bookings/lib/class_eab_event_model.php', true, false);
```

Would be equivalent to this:

```
if (!function_exists('jupiter_init')) {
    function jupiter_init() {
        require_once('../../plugins/events-and-bookings/lib/class_eab_event_model.php');
    }
}
```

But the first code snipper isn't working (but the second one is).  I am placing both in the functions.php file of my child theme right after the initial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a theme, you can use `functions.php` file for all utilize functions. Also this is the best place for all your `require_once` calls.

One trick I would like to recommend for theme development approach:

Don't use direct `require_one` call to include your scripts. Instead of it, use `locate_template` function to load scripts. By using this function, all child themes will be able to override your scripts. So for instance, you have file called `utilize.php`, and it lies in `inc` folder of your theme, then instead of calling `require_once 'inc/utilize.php';`, call `locate_template( 'inc/utilize.php', true, false );`.

Now it will be possible to create `inc/utilize.php` file in a child theme and override parent file.

Comment: check out my update, I tried using require_once in my functions.php and it worked perfectly - when I put locate_template in the same spot, it didn't seem to work -